# Speed up operations over Python Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to speed up a loop over a python Pandas Dataframe. Unfortunately, decades of using low-level languages mean I often struggle to find prepackaged solutions. Note: data is private, but I will see if I can fabricate something and add it into an edit if it helps.

The code has three pandas dataframes: `drugUseDF`, `tempDF`, which holds the data, and `tempDrugUse`, which stores what's been retrieved. I look over every row of `tempDF` (there will be several million rows), retrieving the `prodcode` identified from each row and then using that to retrieve the corresponding value from `use1` column in the `drugUseDF`. I've added comments to help navigate.

This is the structure of the dataframes:

**tempDF**

```
   patid   eventdate consid prodcode issueseq
0  20001  21/04/2005   2728       85        0
1  25001  21/10/2000   3939       40        0
2  25001  21/02/2001   3950       37        0
```

**drugUseDF**

```
   index prodcode  ...      use1 use2
0    171      479  ...  diabetes  NaN
1    172     9105  ...  diabetes  NaN
2    173     5174  ...  diabetes  NaN
```

**tempDrugUse**

```
  use1
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

This is the code:

```
dfList = []                

# if the drug dataframe contains the use1 column. Can this be improved?
if sum(drugUseDF.columns.isin(["use1"])) == 1:
         
    #predine dataframe where we will store the results to be the same length as the main data dataframe.     
    tempDrugUse = DataFrame(data=None, index=range(len(tempDF.index)), dtype=np.str, columns=["use1"])    

    #go through each row of the main data dataframe.
    for ind in range(len(tempDF)): 

        #retrieve the prodcode from the *ind* row of the main data dataframe
        prodcodeStr = tempDF.iloc[ind]["prodcode"]

        #get the corresponding value from the use1 column matching the prodcode column 
        useStr = drugUseDF[drugUseDF.loc[:, "prodcode"] == prodcodeStr]["use1"].values[0]

        #update the storing dataframe
        tempDrugUse.iloc[ind]["use1"] = useStr

    print("[DEBUG] End of loop for use1")
    dfList.append(tempDrugUse)
```

The order of the data matters. I can't retrieve multiple rows by matching the prodcode because each row has a date column. Retrieving multiple rows and adding them to the `tempDrugUse` dataframe could mean that the rows are no longer in chronological date order.

Comment: When a pandas question is of the "how can I speedup […]" kind, I can almost certainly bet that the current code is looping over the rows. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your datasets, explain the logic of the calculation in detail (not how you would do it in a loop!), and provide the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to combine data in two dataframes you should use the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) (similar to JOIN in sql-like languages). Performance wise, you should never loop over the rows - you should use the pandas built-in methods whenever possible. Ordering can be achieved with the [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method.

Comment: Thank you. That was a huge help. Merge did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to map the prodcode from both tables. You can do this via pd.merge (please note the example in the code below differs from your data):

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'patid': [20001, 25001, 25001],
                       'prodcode': [101,102,103]})
drugUseDF = pd.DataFrame({'prodcode': [101,102,103],
                          'use1': ['diabetes', 'hypertonia', 'gout']})
merged_df = pd.merge(tempDF, drugUseDF, on='prodcode', how='left')
```